# El dropdown de Bootstrap 5.3.2 no me funciona

Tags: angular, bootstrap, typescript, web, vscode

Buen dia,

He intentado implementar un dropdown en la ultima version de bootstrap 5.3.2 pero por alguna razon no me funciona. Ya verifique instalar la ultima version con el comando npm install bootstrap@5.3.2
Aqui esta mi codigo, honestamente no se que pueda estar mal, ya inclui el script antes del body. He intentado con versiones anteriores y aun no me funciona. Ayuda please

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
  
      <div style="height: 5vh" class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="nav">
          <a routerLink='/home'>Home</a>
          <a routerLink='/about'>About</a>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
  
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hola amigos, Encontre la solucion, revisando mi archivo angular.json encontre que debia ir de esta forma:             "styles": [
                 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                 "src/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],  ... Pero por alguna razon no se estaban generando estos archivos en el script.. Alguno sabe porque puede ocurrir

Comment: Si estas usando Angular no trabajas en el `index.html`, dentro de `body` solamente debería estar `<app-root></app-root>` y trabajarías ya sea en el `app.component.html` (no recomendado si tienes muchas páginas), o en el respectivo componente.

Comment: Hmmmm... jQuery ya no es necesario desde Bootstrap 5...